# Jade template multiple array in one loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am using Jade for my node.js app, how can I print the data of two arrays into one foreach loop?

```
 each log in logs.logs && date in logs.date
     p #{log}
     cite #{date}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
each log, index in logs.logs
   p #{log}
   cite #{logs.date[index]}
```